# Плавное движение блоков в canvas при наведения мышки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3, canvas

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведения на край (справа/слева) canvas блоки двигались не прерываясь?

А у меня нужно двигать мышкой чтоб блоки двигались:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  function getMousePos(c, evt) {
    var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
  }
  var rectangle = function() {
  this.XPos = 0;
  this.YPos = 0;
  this.Width = 0;
  this.Height = 0;
  }

var cameraXOffset = 0;

c.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
   var mousePos = getMousePos(c, evt);
  if (cameraXOffset < -900){
    cameraXOffset = -900;
  }
  else if(cameraXOffset > 350){
    cameraXOffset = 350;
  }
  
  if(mousePos.x < 350){
      cameraXOffset -= 10
  }
  else if(mousePos.x > 900){
      cameraXOffset += 10
  }
}, false);


var  rect1 = new rectangle();
rect1.XPos = -100;
rect1.YPos = 50;
rect1.Width = 50;
rect1.Height = 50;
// rect1.strokeText("1",0,5);

rect1 = new rectangle();
rect1.XPos = -100;
rect1.YPos = 50;
rect1.Width = 50;
rect1.Height = 50;

var rect2 = new rectangle();
rect2.XPos = 300;
rect2.YPos = 200;
rect2.Width = 75;
rect2.Height = 150;

var rect3 = new rectangle();
rect3.XPos = -375;
rect3.YPos = 300;
rect3.Width = 150;
rect3.Height = 25;

var rect4 = new rectangle();
rect4.XPos = 700;
rect4.YPos = 0;
rect4.Width = 25;
rect4.Height = 250;

var rect5 = new rectangle();
rect5.XPos = 1350;
rect5.YPos = 60;
rect5.Width = 900;
rect5.Height = 200;

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  // Draw the rectangles
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0";
  ctx.fillRect(rect1.XPos + cameraXOffset, rect1.YPos, rect1.Width, rect1.Height);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
  ctx.fillRect(rect2.XPos + cameraXOffset, rect2.YPos, rect2.Width, rect2.Height);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
  ctx.fillRect(rect3.XPos + cameraXOffset, rect3.YPos, rect3.Width, rect3.Height);
  
ctx.fillStyle = "#F0F";
  ctx.fillRect(rect4.XPos + cameraXOffset, rect4.YPos, rect4.Width, rect4.Height);
  
   ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(rect5.XPos + cameraXOffset, rect5.YPos, rect5.Width, rect5.Height);
  
  console.log(cameraXOffset)
}, 3);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="1000" height="400" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенести рассчеты положения в SetInterval, а из MouseMove брать только направление движения.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  function getMousePos(c, evt) {
    var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
  }
  var rectangle = function() {
  this.XPos = 0;
  this.YPos = 0;
  this.Width = 0;
  this.Height = 0;
  }

var cameraXOffset = 0,
    cameraXSpeed = 0;
  
c.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
  var mousePos = getMousePos(c, evt);
  
  if(mousePos.x < 350){
      cameraXSpeed = -0.5
  }
  else if(mousePos.x > 900){
      cameraXSpeed = 0.5
  } else {
      cameraXSpeed = 0
  }
}, false);


var  rect1 = new rectangle();
rect1.XPos = -100;
rect1.YPos = 50;
rect1.Width = 50;
rect1.Height = 50;
// rect1.strokeText("1",0,5);

rect1 = new rectangle();
rect1.XPos = -100;
rect1.YPos = 50;
rect1.Width = 50;
rect1.Height = 50;

var rect2 = new rectangle();
rect2.XPos = 300;
rect2.YPos = 200;
rect2.Width = 75;
rect2.Height = 150;

var rect3 = new rectangle();
rect3.XPos = -375;
rect3.YPos = 300;
rect3.Width = 150;
rect3.Height = 25;

var rect4 = new rectangle();
rect4.XPos = 700;
rect4.YPos = 0;
rect4.Width = 25;
rect4.Height = 250;

var rect5 = new rectangle();
rect5.XPos = 1350;
rect5.YPos = 60;
rect5.Width = 900;
rect5.Height = 200;

setInterval(function() {
  if (cameraXOffset < -900){
    cameraXOffset = -900;
    cameraXSpeed = 0;
  }
  else if(cameraXOffset > 350){
    cameraXOffset = 350;
    cameraXSpeed = 0;
  }
  cameraXOffset += cameraXSpeed;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  // Draw the rectangles
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0";
  ctx.fillRect(rect1.XPos + cameraXOffset, rect1.YPos, rect1.Width, rect1.Height);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
  ctx.fillRect(rect2.XPos + cameraXOffset, rect2.YPos, rect2.Width, rect2.Height);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
  ctx.fillRect(rect3.XPos + cameraXOffset, rect3.YPos, rect3.Width, rect3.Height);
  
ctx.fillStyle = "#F0F";
  ctx.fillRect(rect4.XPos + cameraXOffset, rect4.YPos, rect4.Width, rect4.Height);
  
   ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(rect5.XPos + cameraXOffset, rect5.YPos, rect5.Width, rect5.Height);
  
  console.log(cameraXOffset)
}, 3);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="1000" height="400" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```